# how to avoid duplicates namespace in typescript

Tags: typescript

For example, I have some different objects which data structure like

```
{
   namespace: 'first'|'second'|'third'
}
```

And now I want to add another object which data sturcture is same to above, but its namespace **can not be set to 'first'|‘second’|'third'** , it must a new namespace

How can I do this?

And next I want to add another object again how to constrained the namespace value?

Comment: Provide a possibly non-working example which is more or less semantiacally correct in TS editor ( like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ) to show what you are targeting and what you have

Comment: @Dimava Thanks bro, here is my example https://codesandbox.io/s/xzqu68  , the secondInstance should not use exist namespace which is used by firstInstance,  I have over twenty instances I don't want to exhaustion them... In other words, new Instance can not use the namespace which is used exist instance

Comment: That would be easy in runtime, but I doubt you can do that in compile-time

Comment: @Dimava Thanks for your idea, I try to write a babel plugin or webpack plugin to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Namespaced<K extends string> {
    namespace: K;
}

const nsMap = new Map<string, Namespaced<any>>()

function addNamespace<K extends string, V extends Namespaced<K>>(
    ns: V
): V {
    if (nsMap.has(ns.namespace)) {
        throw new Error(`Trying to cleate duplicate namespace "${ns.namespace}"`)
    }
    nsMap.set(ns.namespace, ns);
    return ns;
}

let a = addNamespace({namespace: 'a'})
//  ^?
let b = addNamespace({namespace: 'b', x: 'b'})
//  ^?
let c = addNamespace({namespace: 'a'}) // throws [ERR]: Trying to cleate duplicate namespace "a"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYQM4AdEQAmAPANLIQAekIh2y2YUoA5gHzIDeAUMn8iEw58SAFzJSAbm4BfbtwQB7EIwHYAsnFzIAvAIgB3ZJtzFGzECwA0aIXgIk4IAJ5s2ACgCU8mAFcQCGDAyshwhIToWPZIZBTUELT05qw2AGpxNHS2USJEZG7uvPwq4qncnqVcRXzAMMjuKiYAdAAWcNgN2E2COQSenlX8Q8hgLVCKRiCGyACiUONQ7gAGACpQzqwjisgIADYQcJDIhL64u8AIhyg9wgTIAEQAJJwq3Xa5MvdL3kNyQ41aJrYCBgTpvXpIGwqTzSIZQEG%20KAgNTSOTcfZgUK6ULhSK3JDuF7vAjiADkcFJMm8AHpqXwAHoAfnRIOQACNsWEIsSCUSIRAyWzSTZKILKTS6cgmSzMQhObieRBCTdogLkOTxchaSMxhN6ABtGYAJSNAF1xGsNpYtjt9ldjqdzpcjircg84PdkNwgA) (ctrl-Enter to run)

Comment: Sry bro, My app is not SPA, so a page can not know namespace is used by another page, nsMap is not shared